Add iCalendar Events (.ics) to Calendars
On Rails 7.1, how can I send an attachment with the content type Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST?
I’m asking because I want to send an email with an ICS file attached, following this recommendation: https://gist.github.com/flandrade/394d9df95e1be2a584f267ae91505239.
If you look into the "eml" of an email sent by Google Calendar, you can observe this content structure:
--000000000000ab3b7c062610bf32
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000ab3b7b062610bf30"

--000000000000ab3b7b062610bf30
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

...email body 64 encoded

--000000000000ab3b7b062610bf30
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

...email body HTML

--000000000000ab3b7b062610bf30
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="UTF-8"; method=REQUEST
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
...
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

--000000000000ab3b7b062610bf30--

--000000000000ab3b7c062610bf32
Content-Type: application/ics; name="invite.ics"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invite.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

...ICS content base 64 formatted

--000000000000ab3b7c062610bf32--

As you can see, there are two parts for the ICS file, each with a different content type.

In my Rails project, I tried this:
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_email
    ...
    mail(from: @email.from, to: @email.to, reply_to: @email.reply_to, subject: @email.subject) do |format|
      format.html { @email.body.html_safe }

      # Inline calendar with text/calendar MIME type and quoted-printable encoding
      attachments['invite.ics'] = {
        mime_type: 'text/calendar; charset=UTF-8; method=REQUEST',
        content_disposition: 'inline; filename="invite.ics"',
        content_transfer_encoding: 'quoted-printable',
        content: ics_content
      }

      # Attached calendar file in application/ics format with base64 encoding
      attachments['invite_attachment.ics'] = {
        mime_type: 'application/ics',
        content_disposition: 'attachment; filename="invite.ics"',
        content_transfer_encoding: 'base64',
        content: Base64.encode64(ics_content)
      }
    end
  end
end

However, the received email still contains two identical attachments in the "eml" file:
Received: from ZR3P278MB1455.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:910:9d::7) by
...
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=IzHjkXif
...
MIME-Version: 1.0

--IzHjkXif
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=duJRsHx4

--duJRsHx4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

... html content

--duJRsHx4--

--IzHjkXif
Content-ID: <672872fa6d88b_109b11c98216a4@XXX>
X-Attachment-Id: 672872fa6d88b_109b11c98216a4@XXX
Content-Type: text/calendar; name=invite.ics
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; name=invite.ics; filename=invite.ics


...ICS content base 64 formatted

--IzHjkXif
Content-Type: text/calendar; name=invite.ics
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; name=invite.ics; filename=invite.ics


...ICS content base 64 formatted
--IzHjkXif--




What you're doing is the correct way.  So this is either a bug in your app or rails. Can you try to isolate the issue and see if you can reproduce it?
